# Is there a Matlab equivalent to Python's cmath.rect?

Tags: python, matlab, complex-numbers, cmath

Is there a Matlab equivalent to Pythons's `cmath.rect(r, phi)` that returns the complex number `x` with polar coordinates `r` and `phi` without resorting to

```
x = r * complex(  cos(phi), sin(phi)  );
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`pol2cart`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pol2cart.html). But the order of the arguments is different, that is, `pol2cart(phi,r)` as follows:

```
[x,y] = pol2cart(pi/6,1)
x =
    0.8660
y =
    0.5000
```

If you need a complex output, you can do the following afterwards:

```
complex(x,y)
ans =    
   0.8660 + 0.5000i
```